# HTML input text cursor position issue

Tags: html, css, input

would just like to ask for your help. when the html page loads, the cursor on the input text is too high or in wrong position:

[image]

but when on focus, the input text cursor is correct:

[image]

found another same question here, but the `line-height` fix does not resolve my issue.

css:

```
input[type=text] {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    height: 50px !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    line-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Include all of the code so we have a [mcve] please.

Comment: The css selector should be `input[type="text"]`

Answer (score 1):

This is padding issue. When you click on input fiend, it is focused and then it get a padding so the cursor is in right position. So set padding like the following -

```
input[type=text] {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    height: 50px !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    line-height: 100% !important;
    padding: adjust according to your choice;
}
```

Comment: still not working, i decided to reduce the line-height according to the cursor but this is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`line-height: normal;`

Usually it helps with similar issues.